# Update record only if LastUpdateDate is the same as DB record

Tags: entity-framework

I am doing a project which needs to update a record only if the last update date in that DB record isn't modified by others.

I can't find any way to do it in EF.

```
    public static void UpdateMaterial(Material updatedMaterial)
    {
        using (var context = new ERPEntities())
        {
            context.materials.Attach(updatedMaterial);
            context.Entry(updatedMaterial).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

I want to save changes only if updatedMaterial.LastUpdateDate equals to DB record's lastUpdateDate. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is called optimistic concurrency.  You need to tell EF to perform the concurrency check for you.  How to do that depends on what version of EF you are using.

1. In [Code First w/ the fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.12), use `IsRowVersion` or `IsConcurrencyToken`
2. In [Code First w/ data annotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx), add a `[ConcurrencyCheck]` annotation to the
3. In [Model First](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cesardelatorre/archive/2008/09/05/optimistic-concurrency-updates-using-entity-framework-in-n-tier-and-n-layer-applications-part-2.aspx), set the Concurrency Mode property for that row to fixed

Comment: I don't think the OP meant **concurrently** 'modified by others', it seems more like a business/validation problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void UpdateMaterial(Material updatedMaterial)
{
    using (var context = new ERPEntities())
    {
        if(updatedMaterial.LastUpdateDate == context.materials.Find(updatedMaterial.Id).LastUpdateDate)
        {
            context.materials.Attach(updatedMaterial);
            context.Entry(updatedMaterial).State = EntityState.Modified; 
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer would cause an extra query (because of the call to `Find`)